# FitSharp FormatException when running tests

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

I installed a clean version of Fitnesse (v20121220) and the latest version of FitSharp (.net 4).

I've created a fitnesse test page but cannot get the tests to run - whenever I try, the tests immediately fail with the following stack trace in the standard output: -

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at fit.Runner.FitSocket.EstablishConnection(String request)
   at fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer.EstablishConnection()
   at fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer.Run(IList`1 CommandLineArguments)
   at fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer.Run(IList`1 commandLineArguments, Memory memory, ProgressReporter reporter)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Run()
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Execute()
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.RunInCurrentDomain(IList`1 commandLineArguments)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.RunInNewDomain(AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup, IList`1 commandLineArguments)
```

And the following error as Internal Exception: -
Internal Exception:

```
FitClient: external process terminated before a connection could be established.
```

My root configuration is pretty basic: -

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -a "FullPathToAcceptanceTests.dll.config" -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,C:\fitnesse\fitsharp\fit.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {c:\fitnesse\fitsharp\Runner.exe}
!path "FullPathToAcceptanceTests.dll"
```

Obviously the FullPathToAcceptanceTests points to where my fitnesse acceptance tests code is.

I don't understand why this is happening - I've used Fitnesse / Fitsharp before without problems, but this just doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: Small update - it's not my configuration per se. I sometimes need to reboot or log off / log on to get it to work. If I trace what it is I'll answer it here...

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem might be caused by running Fitnesse on default 80 port.
FitLibrary and Fit are sometimes using the same port, which might cause an issue.
Try using different port.

Answer (score 0):

I have

```
!path "FullPathToAcceptanceTests.dll"
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r "fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,C:\fitnesse\fitsharp\fit.dll" %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {c:\fitnesse\fitsharp\Runner.exe}
```